# Python matplotlib installation on centos error

Tags: python, matplotlib, centos7

I have issues installing `matplotlib` on CentOS 7. I have installed everything `freetype`, `libpng-devel`. I don't know how to resolve this.

I tried to install `yum`. It did work, but then while I was importing, I got an error.

**Optional backend extensions**

```
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]

                qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]

                pyside: no  [PySide not found]

               gtk3agg: no  [Requires gtk3 development files to be

                        installed.]

             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]

                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]

                 tkagg: no  [TKAgg requires Tkinter.]

                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]

                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]

                   agg: yes [installing]

                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]

             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]


OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES

                dvipng: no

           ghostscript: no

                 latex: no

               pdftops: no

============================================================================

                        * The following required packages can not be built:

                        * freetype
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to install the `freetype` [devel](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/26641425/dir/centos_7/com/freetype-devel-2.4.11-9.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) package:

Comment: I uninstalled freetype and then reinstalled it. That seem to have worked !!!

Comment: good, the main problem seemed to be the freetype package normally if you have a package installed and you get an error it is because you need the dev package, did you actually install the devel package?

Comment: aah ok !! yaah I realized that I did not install the freetype dev.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing any of the gui libraries that the interactive backends use.  Matplotlib is installing correctly, but isn't able to find Tkinter, Qt, Wx, or Gtk, so it can't display interactive plots.

Try installing `tkinter`, `tkinter-devl` and `python-tk` if they're not already installed (or if you'd prefer Qt, Wx, or Gtk as the interactive backend, install those).